# how to add extra labels at load event in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Code is as below

```
chart: {
    type: "funnel",
    marginBottom: 25,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var chart = this;
            Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
                chart.options.labels.items.push({
                    html: "less confident" + i,
                    style: { left: 550, top: 50 }
                });
                p.dataLabel.attr({
                    x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
                    "text-anchor": "middle"
                });
            });
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're trying to add a label for every point. Highcharts has build in functionality for this called **data labels**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels

Another approach is to use `SVGRenderer.label`: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label